# For x in [list] does not iterate on each pass

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

Task: To find 2 values in a list which add up to make a target value.
Problem: for x in sums doesnt seem to increment after each pass.

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for i in nums:
        for x in nums:
            print(x)
            print(nums.index(x))
            sum = x + i
            print(sum)
            if sum == target and nums.index(x) != nums.index(i):
                return [nums.index(x), nums.index(i)]
```

Expected return: [0, 1] but does not return anything.
HELP.

Comment: do not use sum as a variable name it is a built in function, it can override.

Comment: `if sum == target and nums.index(x) != nums.index(i)` If this is never true, then the function will not return anything.

Comment: Note that `index` only returns the *first* index from the start of the list where the element is found. It doesn't know what the actual index for that element is, so if the element appears multiple times, it will also return the first index. For your suspicion though, `for` will always advance to the next element when one iteration finishes.

Comment: Also, this code appears to work for cases where the aforementioned `index` issue doesn't cause problems.

Comment: @Carcigenicate how do you suggest I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops should be iterating the indexes rather than the contents of the list, this will make it easier to return the index once the correct combination is found.  Additionally your inner loop only needs to iterate from the index that your outer loop is currently at to the end of the list. This will avoid repeating the same calculations and accidentally doubling the same index.  Finally you should return an empty list if two numbers that add up to the target are never found.

You can achieve this with:

```
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
            if target - nums[i] == nums[j]:
                return [i,j]
    return []
```

Comment: may i ask why you've stated if target-nums[i] == nums[j] as opposed to nums[i] + nums[j] == target. Does it make a difference?

Comment: No.  The two calculations are identical.   @ak231472